# Calling MySQL stored procedure in PHP only updates one row

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that should update a column in a table. When I run

```
CALL recalculate_city_ids();
```

from a MySQL prompt, the correct number of rows are updated (a few hundred). When I run the command from PHP, only a single row is updated and I get no error.

Here's the PHP:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname' );
$result = $con->query( 'call recalculate_city_ids()' );
mysql_close($con);
```

And the SQL for the sproc:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS recalculate_city_ids;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE recalculate_city_ids()
    READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE o_id INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE o_latitude FLOAT;
        DECLARE o_longitude FLOAT;
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE cur_users CURSOR FOR SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM user WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL ORDER BY fname;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

        OPEN cur_users;
        users: LOOP
            FETCH cur_users INTO o_id, o_latitude, o_longitude;

            IF done=1 THEN
                LEAVE users;
            END IF;

            SELECT @closest_city_distance:=fn_distance_cosine(o_latitude, o_longitude, latitude, longitude) AS distance, @closest_city_id:=id AS id FROM category WHERE zone="city" AND active=1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;

            UPDATE user SET city_id = IF(@closest_city_distance<=30, @closest_city_id, 0) WHERE id=o_id;
        END LOOP users;
        CLOSE cur_users;
    END
    $$
```

I can run other queries from PHP using mysqli (also tried the mysql object). I'm also unable to create stored procedures from PHP (no error) and had to do that part from a MySQL prompt as well.

PHP and my MySQL prompt are using the same username.

Comment: I don't know why is this not working, but it can be written in PHP using SQL only for SELECT and UPDATE.

Comment: Are you maybe printing "updated: $result"? That would print a "1". I did a quick test run with a trimmed down version of your SP on tables with timestamps being updated and the proper rows were updated.

Comment: I'd rather keep it in the DB for performance reasons, since it might be many thousands of rows that need to be updated.

I'm not printing anything. Just checking the effect in MySQL, which is where I see the single row updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that PHP doesn't like it when a query returns multiple result sets. I don't really need to return anything since this is just a glorified `UPDATE` statement, so I changed my

`SELECT @closest_city_distance:=fn_distance_cosine...` query to

`SELECT fn_distance_cosine(o_latitude, o_longitude, latitude, longitude) as distance,id into closest_city_distance, closest_city_id FROM category WHERE zone="city" AND active=1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;`

Since that was the only place a result set was getting returned, eliminating the returned sets fixed the problem.